80s novel - teenagers transported to planet
I remember that a group of teenagers go to a disco and then the floor gives way and hours later they wake up on another planet.
To stop the earth getting annihilated one of the boys needs to win a battle for survival. I also remember an alien called the box which had sharp teeth inside it.
It would lure you in and eat you.
I have been looking for this book for about 30 years and found a book similar called Transit by Edmond Cooper.

"A Splendid Chaos" by John Shirley
starts the way you describe. From the book's first chapter:

Remembered a disco. Sure it was a disco. Only... it was in the middle of an intersection, right smack in the middle of the road.
They'd been walking along, Zero and Bowler and Angie and Cisco, looking for a way out of the sticky-hot Manhattan night ...
[...]
The floor got soft.
It was softer than putty, but not as soft as quicksand. They sank into it -- everyone in the club but Artichoke-Face -- and everyone stopped trying to fight the sinking after thirty seconds of babbling and crying out because a sweet, seductive sleepyness came over them.

This detail only matches weakly:

To stop the earth getting annihilated one of the boys needs to win a battle for survival.

I don't recall any mention of Earth being in danger of annihilation. The expeditions to the Progress Stations are done for improving the life of the abductees on the alien planet, but they are indeed part of the battle for survival staged by the Meta, as the alien abductors are called.

I also remember an alien called the box which had sharp teeth inside it.

A Boxed Liar (which is described several times to look like a box) almost succeeds in luring Zero, the books protagonist, into its maw. But there is no mention of teeth.

I have been looking for this book for about 30 years ...

"A Splendid Chaos" was first published 1988, which makes it an 80s novel and matches your time frame.
